# Apache IpMatch?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Apache allows to apply certain configuration using FileMatch, Location and the rest.
Is it possible to apply a certain configuration using IP as a condional

Something like this:

# some rules here.

Answer (score 0):

[SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) can check for the IP address, and then you have [several options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/env.html) for things you can do with the environment variables once they're set.

Basic access control ([allow](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#allow) and [deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html#deny)) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) can also work with IP addresses directly.